# Which one of these is correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, idioms

1 It would make him to being / to be a good person.

Which one ,and why?Do both?

2 There is an idiom , 'turn on head'.Eg- turn the game on its head.

It will turn the placement on its head.
But
'It will turn the placements on their head' is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, these are two separate questions. Secondly, they probably belong in [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). But here are some answers anyway.

1. You would just say "It would make him a good person."
2. I'm not sure what "placement" means in this context, but assuming it makes sense, it should be "It will turn the placements on their heads." (Each has its own head, so you have to use the plural.)